# Using e.target.value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am a Reactjs developer and I am learning typescript, I am doing this project with a movie API, so for me to be able to build the search functionality into the website, I need e.target.value, but typescript is giving me errors that I do not understand. So I will post my code and thank you in advance!

App.tsx

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState<iMovies['movie']>([])

const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, value: any): void => {
e.preventDefault()
setSearch(e.target.value)
}
```

next I would fetch the api and use the `search` state/value to put it into the api so the app knows what to search for

this is the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKOm3.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in a misunderstanding of the `React.useState` hook, and not necessarily in your `e.target.value` use in the `onChange` function.

`React.useState` is holding the type of `IMovies['movie']`, which seems to be

```
type IMovies['movie'] = Array<{
  id: number;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  poster_path: string;
  background_path: string;
}>;
```

Youre having a problem like trying to put an `integer` value inside of a variable of type `string`

```
const num: number = 'hello world!'; // ERROR: type string is not assignable to number
```

`e.target.value` is of type `string`, and does not fit the shape of your `React.useState`, which is using the type described above.

You should either change `React.useState` to hold a `string` value in state for your query, or you should find a way inside of your `onChange` function to convert the `e.target.value` into a type that matches your current `React.useState`.